# Ajax posts on socket.io

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, node.js, socket.io

1)I wanna make an online quiz. I use socket.io just listen to nodes, that's all.
Need to use ajax for the retrieving questions and answering them from database with php.
I am generating random number in app.js(node js server file). emit this number to client side.
ie. `

> socket.emit('question',randomnumber);

`
client side:

> socket.on('question',function(data){
>
> $.post("question.php",{"id":data}, function(res){
>
> $('#question-area').html(res);
>
> });
>
> });

when i use this method console says ' localhost:3000/question.php not found '

So how can i use $.post method while my client address is localhost:3000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your $.post from

`$.post("question.php",{"id":data}, function(res){`

to

`$.post("http://localhost/question.php",{"id":data}, function(res){`